# 'Memory stream is not expandable' but size of array is the same?

Tags: c#, multithreading, encryption

I am trying to multithread AES in C# but I can't seem to fix this weird exception. My buffer sizes are exactly the same but it still says it can't expand maybe you can see the error this is for a file of size 101 bytes.

In the while loop it will skip if and go inside the else creating (one thread?) that writes a not encrypted buffer to an encrypted buffer. After that is done to synchronize I want to write the encrypted buffer to a file in the runworkerComplete function. The issue presents itself when I try to write the not encrypted buffer into a encrypted buffer. The error message puzzles me since the size of the second buffer is created with the length of the first buffer but yet is says it can't expand the memory!?

```
static List<BackgroundWorker> threadCompany = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static List<BackgroundWorker> listWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static List<BackgroundWorker> listFreeWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static FileStream fsIn;
static string file;
static byte[] key;
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1000;
static FileStream outFile;

public static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string sKey, ProgressBar progress)
{
    String fileName = inputFile;
    fileName = "\\" + fileName.Split('\\').Last();
    var progres = new Progress<int>(value => progress.Value = value);
    file = outputFile + fileName;

    fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
    outFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);

    key = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(sKey);

    for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        listWorkers.Add(worker);
        listFreeWorkers.Add(worker);
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
    double numBlocks = Math.Ceiling(((double)fileInfo.Length) / BLOCK_SIZE);

    int ixCurrentBlock = 0;
    while (ixCurrentBlock < numBlocks)
    {
        //check if any free workers    
        if (listFreeWorkers.Count > 0)
        {
            //Get the worker, remove it from the list
            BackgroundWorker freeWorker = listFreeWorkers[0];
            listFreeWorkers.RemoveAt(0);

            //read the next block of the file
            int bytes;

            if (ixCurrentBlock < numBlocks - 1)
            {
                bytes = fsIn.Read(buffer, ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
                freeWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(ixCurrentBlock, buffer));
                threadCompany.Remove(freeWorker);
            }
            else  //special handling for last block
            {
                MessageBox.Show((ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE) + " " + (int)(fileInfo.Length - ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE)); // 0 101
                bytes = fsIn.Read(buffer, ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE, (int)(fileInfo.Length - ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE));
                freeWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(ixCurrentBlock, new byte[(int)(fileInfo.Length - ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE)]));

                threadCompany.Remove(freeWorker);
            }

            //now pass it to a worker
            //advance to the next block
            ixCurrentBlock++;

            //update the UI status here
            // ...
        }
        else //no workers free
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }

    //if we make it to here we have sent off all the blocks
    //now we wait for the threads to complete

    bool threadsRunning = false;
    while (threadsRunning)
    {
        threadsRunning = false;
        foreach (BackgroundWorker worker in listWorkers)
        {
            threadsRunning |= worker.IsBusy;
        }

        //if still running, wait and try again in 50ms

        if (threadsRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}

private static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<int, byte[]> t = e.Argument as Tuple<int, byte[]>;

    int blockIndex = (int)t.Item1;
    byte[] inBuffer = (byte[])t.Item2;
    byte[] outBuffer = new byte[inBuffer.Length];

    //using keyword will automatically close the stream

    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream(outBuffer)) // issue may be here?
    {
        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(outStream,
                          RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                          CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // I want to write inbuffer non encrypted to outbuffer encrypted.
            cs.Write(inBuffer, blockIndex, inBuffer.Length);
        }
    }

    e.Result = Tuple.Create(blockIndex, outBuffer);
}

private static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message + " "); // memory is not expendable 

    Tuple<int, byte[]> t = e.Result as Tuple<int, byte[]>;

    int blockIndex = (int)t.Item1;
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])t.Item2;

    //assumes you have a class variable, _outFile, that is an open filestream
    outFile.Write(buffer, blockIndex, buffer.Length);
    outFile.Close();
    //add the worker back to the free workers list
    listFreeWorkers.Add((BackgroundWorker)sender);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption and decryption arn't the same size to solve this issue flush the stream (already implied with the `using` statement) toarray the stream to your outbuffer.

SOLUTION

```
private static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Tuple<int, byte[]> t = e.Argument as Tuple<int, byte[]>;

            int blockIndex = (int)t.Item1;
            byte[] inBuffer = (byte[])t.Item2;
            byte[] outBuffer;

            //using keyword will automatically close the stream

            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream()) // issue may be here?
            {
                AesCryptoServiceProvider RMCrypto = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(outStream,
                                  RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                                  CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    // I want to write inbuffer non encrypted to outbuffer encrypted.
                    cs.Write(inBuffer, blockIndex, inBuffer.Length);

                }
                    outBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
             }

            e.Result = Tuple.Create(blockIndex, outBuffer);
        }
```